# databinding object sets the content view, but is actually null

Tags: android, androidx, android-databinding

So, I'm trying to add dataBinding to my application, it worked fine in an earlier application, but here it just doesn't seem to be working.
Here's the code.
SelectActivity.java

```
package com.example.BoardsRevision;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.BoardsRevision.databinding.ActivitySelectBinding;

public class SelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivitySelectBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_select);
        if(binding==null) {
            Log.d("meraTAG", "onCreate: Binding is null" );
        }

//        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("name")!=null){
//            String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
//            Log.d("username", "onCreate: " + name);
//        }
//
//        binding.buttonTrivia.setOnClickListener(v -> {
//            startActivity(new Intent(SelectActivity.this, TriviaActivity.class));
//        });
    }
}``
```

activity_select.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/royal_purple"
        tools:context=".SelectActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonQuestions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/extra_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/faded_orange"
            android:text="@string/practice_questions"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonCases"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.965" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCases"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/extra_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF913E"
            android:text="@string/real_life_cases"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTrivia"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/extra_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF913E"
            android:text="@string/trivia"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonCases"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I have added the layout tags in the activity_select.xml file and
I have tried using binding = ActivitySelectBinding.inflate()
but it always invoked a null pointer exception when I tried to use the buttonTrivia.. So I added the if statement to see if binding itself was null.. and it is. that if statement is true.. I can see it in the log.

The interesting thing is, the view is being set, but as soon as I try to access any views using the binding object the app crashes.
Here's what the RUN tab says

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.boardsrevision10, PID: 9007
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.boardsrevision10/com.example.BoardsRevision.SelectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.Button com.example.BoardsRevision.databinding.ActivitySelectBinding.buttonTrivia' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.Button com.example.BoardsRevision.databinding.ActivitySelectBinding.buttonTrivia' on a null object reference
    at com.example.BoardsRevision.SelectActivity.onCreate(SelectActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: How does your R.layout.activity_select look like?

Comment: I have also added the code for activity_select...

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to set a content-view, as it already knows which layout to inflate.

See directory "java (generated)" below "java" in the IDE, there should be a generated binding.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.mDataBinding = ActivitySelectBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
}
```

Keeping `R.layout.activity_select` is only good for the IDE to know which XML file to link:

```
private static final int resId = R.layout.activity_select;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that package names should start with lowercase.. I don't know if that was the problem, but somehow after changing the package name everything seems to work fine.

Secondly, I think using
`binding = ActivitySelectBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater); setContentView(binding.getRoot());`
also did the trick